# Angular2 http service not found

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

cant get a simple http service to work in angular2. I just get 404 on the service for some reason. It does not contain any functionality yet, but I seems that the DI does not work.

As soon as I add TestService when bootstrapping the application i get the following. GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/testService 404 (Not Found)

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS 2 Tutorial Series</title>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>        
        <script>
            System.config({
                transpiler: 'typescript',
                typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }
            });
            System.import('./app/app.ts');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <my-app>loading...</my-app>

    </body>
</html>
```

app.ts

```js
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {TestService} from 'testService';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>',
})

class AppComponent {
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [TestService]);
```

TestService.ts

```js
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
export class TestService {
    constructor(public http: Http){        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I just ran into this, fixed it by adding the script reference to the http bundle:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Tried it after remembering that I added a similar resource after implementing routing.  Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

This is because by Default your 'http.dev.js' is not sourced

**Step 1** : *index.html*

```
Include 'http.dev.js'
```

```html
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

**Step 2:** *main.ts*

Add import and add 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'

```js
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**STEP: 3** *app.component.ts*

import Http and use it

```js
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';

constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').subscribe((data) => {
      this.response = data._body;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `Http` by supplying it as a provider. There are 2 ways to accomplish this:

1) at a global level you can specify when you bootstrap the application:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [TestService, Http]);
```

2) inside the component you are trying to use it within:

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [Http]
})
public class ...
```

**NOTE** you will also have to `import`/`require` Http when you are supplying it as a provider. This will allow angular's DI to discern what will be injected.

Comment: For example adding Http to my app.ts and importing Http from 'angular2/http' gives the same error, GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/angular2/http 404 (Not Found)

Comment: You still need to set up `Http` as a provider, so DI knows how to inject it

Comment: Still the same, 404 not found. I even stripped out everything and only have the import {Http} from 'angular2/http' and still get not found. Must be something wrong with the libraries? As soon as the import for http is present, regardless of file I get the 404 error.

Comment: Ah I see, you are having a much different issue. This seems like a bundling issue or reference issue, you will need to post your build/deploy information. I would even suggest asking that in a different question. That being said, you will still need to set up `Http` as a provider once you get the build/deploy set up

Comment: Ok, sorry maybe my question was not clear enough :) I just followed this, http://tutorialedge.net/getting-started-with-angular-2 only installed liveserver and typescript tsc via npm, nothing else.

Comment: No problem at all. The link you shared was to an alpha version. I suggest you take a look at the official getting started guide here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html